# Not able to change cell date format with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue with the below code.
It basically supposes to open an excel file and change the date format for a range of cells.  When I'm trying to do that nothing happens.
When I'm opening the same file manually and apply the second Sub the date format changes with no problem.
I must highlight that when the file is opened manually in the column that supposes to be changed I can see *****, when expanding the column by double-clicking it, it shows the date.
When opened by code you can see the date straight away in the same column.

Any Idea why this is happening and how to overcome it?

```
Sub open_file()

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\rszczerbinski\Desktop\FTP Files\mes_kpi_packing.csv"
'Call select_date_format

End Sub

Sub select_date_format()
'
' chage date format
'

'
    Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"

End Sub
```

Comment: You try "dd/mm/yyyy"?  Hmmm. Just tried it on a csv I have open in excel and the code within the sub worked fine...

(I do assume you removed the comment from 'Call select_date_format when your running it?)

Comment: **IMPORT** instead of **OPEN**, so you can tell Excel the format of the date in the csv file.  (eg. **Workbooks.OpenText** or set up a connection using the legacy wizard or Power Query).  Not sure if **.OpenText** will work on a csv file, or if you have to change it to a txt file.

Comment: Might be worth trying: `Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\rszczerbinski\Desktop\FTP Files\mes_kpi_packing.csv", Local:=True`

Comment: Tried "dd/mm/yyyy" it is not working, yeah the comment was removed, I just tried to run the codes one by one.

Comment: Workbooks.OpenText  opens the csv but again no difference

Comment: Rory, that worked Thanks very much !!!